# DDD : Can you event storm on your own?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've recently been introduced into Domain Driven Design and we've done a lot of event storming in a simulated environment with a lot of people.

Now I'm back in the real world and I've been given a task but I need deeper insight in the process.

Does it make sense to go out event storming on your own to do this? Or is event storming on your own just plain silly?

Answer (score 2):

[Event Storming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_storming#Requirements) article has the following to say on the matter:

> It is important for an event storming workshop to have the right
>   people in presence. This includes people who know the questions to ask
>   (typically developers) and those who know the answers (domain
>   experts).

So no, I think that's a definite no.  Though if you're generating ideas for yourself, there's nothing wrong with that.  I simply don't think it can be called event storming without others.  If anything, have a peer review your ideas to get some feedback for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "on your own". If you mean with your company without help from externals, then yes, go for it. You will be not perfect in the methodology nor getting through without bumps (mainly caused by human interactions), but you will learn and improve.

But if you mean with me, being the only person modelling, then better not, if you have to produces insight on your domain. I think this is the guess, that Neil had in mind.